# Vue 2 Vuex - update values via form or add new item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have following template:

```
<template>

    <div class="is-half">
        <form @submit.prevent="save">

            <input type="hidden" name="bookID" :value="book.id">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Title</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Title" :value="book.title">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control">
                <div class="select">
                    <select>
                      <option
                        v-for="author in this.$store.state.authors"
                        :value="author.name"
                        :selected="author.name == book.author"
                        >{{ author.name }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Description</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Description" :value="book.description"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control">
                <button class="button is-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                book : {
                    id: null,
                    title: '',
                    isbn: '',
                    author: '',
                    description: '',
                    added: ''

                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            save(book) {
                console.log(this.book);
            }
        },
        created() {

            if(this.$store.state.book != 'undefined'){
                this.book = Object.assign({}, this.$store.state.book);
            }
        },
        computed: {}

    }

</script>

<style></style>
```

I am trying to update the value of selected item, but whenever I press save, the object has the same values which it gets on load. 
How can I update values if the I load new object, or insert new object if **id** is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your question, the problem is that when you type something in the input, it doesn't update the model.

The problem is you're using `:value` to bind the values and this is a one-way binding. For 2 way binding replace all `:value` with `v-model`: `v-model="book.title"`